# Why when downloading html page source the saved html size is not the same each time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the original page i'm trying to save it's source.

[page original](http://www.usgodae.org/ftp/outgoing/fnmoc/models/navgem_0.5/latest_data/)

If i will make in chrome on this page right click with the mouse and save as the html file will be allways 2037 KB

But in my program using WebClient each time the saved html file have a differenet size:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Downloading Main Url");
                client.DownloadFile(mainurl, path_exe + "\\page.html");
                if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    client.CancelAsync();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

The link in the variable mainurl is:

http://www.usgodae.org/ftp/outgoing/fnmoc/models/navgem_0.5/latest_data/

The same as the link above but when saving it manual the size is the same all the time when using my program it's not the same. What could be the problem ?

Also i noticed that when making saving as it will save it fast with same size.

In my program with the WebClient it's taking about 7 seconds to download it sometimes it might take 30 seconds or more if it's downloading the size as manual. Something wrong with the WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler and check what's going on. There might be certain cookies which are stored in your browser. thats why you are getting full source code when downloading directly but not using webclient or there are certain javascript which we can't download using webclient.

Use httpWebRequest as it gives more control for cookies header and other protocols.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
 string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
 sr.Close();
 response.Close();
 return html;
```

It's just an example to download source code. If you need to modify cookies etc.. you might need to modify it.